# How to avoid loops duplication?

Tags: javascript

There is a specific logic for filtering collection:

```
    let rows = (collection || []).filter((item: any) => {
      const { country, year, productType, units, productSubtype } = item;
      const cond1 = unitsPlain.length ? unitsPlain.includes(units) : true;
      const cond3 = years.includes(year);
      const cond2 = country === value;
      const cond4 = productType === key && !productSubtype;

      return cond1 && cond2 && cond3 && cond4;
    });

    if (!rows.length) {
      rows = collection.filter((item: any) => {
        const { country, year, productType, productSubtype } = item;
        const cond3 = years.includes(year);
        const cond2 = country === value;
        const cond4 = productSubtype === key && !productType;

        return cond2 && cond3 && cond4;
      });
    }

    if (!rows.length) {
      rows = collection.filter((item: any) => {
        const { country, year, productType, productSubtype } = item;
        const cond3 = years.includes(year);
        const cond2 = country === value;
        const cond4 = productSubtype === key || productType === key;

        return cond2 && cond3 && cond4;
      });
    }
```

As you noticed I try to launch the next loop to find elements of prev returns empty result.

How to improve it?

Comment: not answer but "productSubtype === key || productType === key;" what does this line do?

Comment: It tried to find elements by two properties if one of them exist

Comment: oh sorry i thought both was same property... btw what you think about to have three arrays for each filter, loop in collection only once and push items in different arrays depending on their filter?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-wqdzid?file=index.js

Comment: Thank you, but how as result return only one array? Now you have collection

Comment: Would a `while` loop work? `while (!rows.length) {
      rows = collection.filter((item: any) => {
        const { country, year, productType, productSubtype } = item;
        const cond3 = years.includes(year);
        const cond2 = country === value;
        const cond4 = productSubtype === key && !productType;

        return cond2 && cond3 && cond4;
      });
    }`
If you only want to check it *x* times (2 times, in your example), then you could add a counter to your while condition.

Comment: @Dalama you can check length of the arrays and use it if it is not empty (for example if filter1.length > 0 then row = filteredCollections.filter1)

Comment: you can also check in forEach that if one of the three arrays length will be greater than 0, then use only one filter which suits this array and forget other two filters

Comment: you can only save cond2 and cond3 into a own function. but all other conditions are different

Comment: You can post this as answer, I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain filters

```
let rows = (collection || []).filter(callbackFn).filter(callbackFn)
```

Comment: No, I can not, because the next filter should work only when prev returns empty array

Comment: Oh sorry, too fast answering... Then maybe you can use every and check for each filter? More info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48834275/good-way-to-chain-filter-functions-in-javascript